# Retrieving Type for ITypeInfo fails with TypeLoadException in some scenarios prior to .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, com-interop

I'm working on some code which explores COM objects without using COM interop assemblies. At one point I try to iterate over the ITypeInfos of an `IDispatch` instance (reference cleanup/releases omitted):

```
var dispatch = instance as IDispatch;
if (dispatch != null)
{
    uint count;
    dispatch.GetTypeInfoCount(out count);
    for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ptrTypeInfo;
        dispatch.GetTypeInfo(i, 0, out ptrTypeInfo);
        var itype = Marshal.GetTypeForITypeInfo(ptrTypeInfo); // fails here
    }
}
```

But for some COM instances, the call to `Marshal.GetTypeForITypeInfo` always fails with a `TypeLoadException`, e.g.:

> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'SOCOMApplicationLib.IApplication' from assembly 'SOCOMApplicationLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The mystery to me is: this error only occurs prior to .NET 4.0.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour, a hint where to look more thoroughly or a factor I forgot to consider?

**Update**: I changed my strategy: instead of trying to use `Marshal.GetTypeForITypeInfo` together with `Marshal.GetMethodInfoForComSlot` in order to retrieve the names of available methods I now work with the `TYPEATTR` and `FUNCDESC` structs. But nevertheless I'm curious why my original approach didn't work reliably.

Comment: Seems like the problem was a run-of-the-mill type load exception, which you can debug/diagnose via fusion logging.

Comment: I think I checked the fusion log, but I'm not 100% sure, so I'll check it (again) as soon as I can.